# Running 64-bit apache mesos on 32 bit non-Linux non-Mac OS operating system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mac-osx, operating-system

I am exploring Apache Mesos for my next project. As I was going through the mesos documentation, I realised that it can be installed on a Linux(64 bit) and Mac (64 bit) machine. That should be fine with my current setup. But I'm interested in knowing is there any way to run mesos on a 32 bit OS? Also, does it support any other operating system than Mac and Linux?

Comment: You can't be serious.

Comment: You mean there are other operating systems other than Mac OS and Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your faint only hope would be to get the source, compile it against 32-bit libraries and install it.

Yes, if you were to do a lot of work, you might be able to get binaries generated for Windows but that is a low percentage proposition as well. You'd need to compile all dependent libraries needed and ensure they work.  Sounds like a pretty ambitious project this one.

The suggested method would be to install a 64-bit Linux OS and work from that.

A 64-bit binary will NOT work on a 32-bit OS.

However, a 32-bit binary MAY work on a 64-bit OS.